# $resource.query() parameters fail to arrive at server

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Trying to implement a RESTful API using Node.js and Angular.

On the client side, I define a resource called `songResource` with the `$resource` function in Angular. 
I then call the API with this method:

```
$scope.displayArray = songResource.query(
    parameters, // an object containing various settings
    function(value, responseHeaders) { // success callback
        console.log('Success!',parameters); 
        ...
    },
    function(httpResponse) { // error callback
        console.log('Error!');
        ...
    }
);
```

On the server side, the route resolves, but the parameters do not come over. (In other words, `req.params` is an 
empty object.) The rest of the service retrieves and sends zero records. My client receives the zero records and
hits the success callback, where I can tell that the API call succeeded.

Why aren't the parameters coming over to the API, and how do I fix this?

Comment: If you are wondering why I didn't post any server-side code: The route is a simple `app.get`, and the first line of the code is `console.log(req.params)` that shows me that my parameters aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what I was doing wrong. My parameters come in through the query string. Therefore, I need to use `req.query` rather than `req.params` to get the parameters.